# Error parsing parameter '--environment': Expected: ',', received: 'EOF' for input: Variables={AMI_ID=}

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to run an AWS command in my pipeline and I'm getting this error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--environment': Expected: ',', received: 'EOF' for input:
Variables={AMI_ID=}
```

Here's my full command being run in my pipeline:

```
update_lambda:
  stage: update_lambda
  script:
    - aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name $LAMBDA_ARN --environment Variable={AMI_ID=$AMI_ID}
```

I'm referencing examples I found online, what other ways could I try?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the `$AMI_ID` variable is empty.

Comment: @lxg that fixed the issue- only part of my pipeline was running and the part that gives that variable a value wasn't running